# Как узнать состояние клавиши Key_Space (нажата или нет) в PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, keypressevent, qevent, keyreleaseevent

Что надо добавить или изменить, чтобы выводилось текущее состояние клавиши?

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
import sys


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.status_space = 0
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.print_status)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)
        self.timer.start()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 300)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.status_space = 1

    def print_status(self):
        print(self.status_space)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63193311/detect-external-keyboard-events-in-pyqt5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.Qt import *


keyNameFromValue = {}
keyNameFromString = {}
for k, v in vars(Qt).items():
    if isinstance(v, Qt.Key):
        keyNameFromValue[v] = k
        keyNameFromString[QKeySequence(v).toString()] = k


class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.box = QLabel(self)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.box)

    def event(self, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.InputMethod:
            s = event.commitString()
            if s:
                self.box.setText('InputMethod > {}: {}'.format(
                     keyNameFromString.get(s, '(Unknown)'), s))
                self.box.adjustSize()
        return super().event(event)

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        print(f'Нажата клавиша:  {event.text()}')
        if not event.isAutoRepeat():
            self.box.setText('KeyPress > {}: {}'.format(
                keyNameFromValue.get(event.key()), event.text()))
            #print(f'Нажата клавиша: {event.text()}')
            self.box.adjustSize()
        super().keyPressEvent(event)

    def keyReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if not event.isAutoRepeat():
            self.box.setText('KeyRelease > {}: {}'.format(
                keyNameFromValue.get(event.key()), event.text()))
            print(f'keyReleaseEvent: {event.text()}')
            self.box.adjustSize()
        super().keyReleaseEvent(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setFont(QFont("Times", 12, QFont.Bold))
    ex = Window()
    ex.resize(300, 70)
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]